# Are the GitHub repository id numbers permanent?

Tags: github

The [GitHub v.3 API for repository data](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/) returns an integer identifier for a given repository. This identifier is the value of the field `id` in the data returned. In this example, it is the number 1296269:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1296269,
    "owner": {
      "login": "octocat",
       ... stuff omitted for brevity ...
    },
    "name": "Hello-World",
    "full_name": "octocat/Hello-World",
       ... stuff omitted for brevity ...
  }
]
```

Is a given identifier value *ever* reused once it is assigned to a repository, even if a repository or its owner account is subsequently deleted? In other words, are the identifiers unique and permanent, and never reused for any other repositories, ever?

In this context, I don't mean simply renaming a repository; that would not count as "reusing" it in the same sense, nor would replacing the content of a repository completely with other content.  I am trying to understand specifically whether the GitHub `id` values are ever "recycled", if you will.

(I honestly searched in the GitHub documentation and the web, but could not find a statement either way. If I missed it, I apologize and would be happy to be pointed to the appropriate documentation.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Ruby toolkit for the GitHub API](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb) relies on the uniqueness of a GitHub id since 2014: see [issue 483](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/issues/483) and [PR 485](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/pull/485).

At the time (2014), [renamed repo were not supported](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/issues/483#issuecomment-45763366), but since then ([April 2015](https://developer.github.com/changes/2015-04-17-preview-repository-redirects/)), [they are](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29448464/6309)

> If you have information about the repo before it was renamed, you should have the id which is returned by the API. If you do then to have a resilient access to the repository, you just need to do

```
GET /repositories/1234
```

> And you'll always get the repository, regardless of whether the name changes (assuming you still have access to it).

Comment: Is there any documentation for `id` field? I couldn't find anywhere on [GitHub API Documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/), unfortunately.

Comment: @Emadpres I do not. Maybe GitHub support has more on that id.